# "ls: cannot open directory '.': No such file or directory" in Git Bash (in VS Code terminal)

Tags: linux, command-line, bash

I am working in a Git Bash terminal within Visual Studio Code. For some reason, when the behavior of the terminal changed so that if I execute `ls`, the result is

```
ls: cannot open directory '.': No such file or directory
```

Restarting a new terminal fixes the problem, so I don't need help with fixing it, but I wonder why this is even possible. How can the current directory `.` not exist?

Comment: Have you checked what is the current folder ?

Comment: Yes, `pwd` returns the name of the folder I'm in.

Comment: Well, if it's not consistent, you need to tell us what you do before it happens. Unless it happens by itself which I doubt.

Comment: It has only happened once, so I don't know how to reproduce it. I'm just curious why it's even possible to happen at all. Can `.` be redefined, somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can happen when the current working directory is deleted or moved away from underneath you.

Example using two terminals/sessions (I'll put a no-op `: 1;` and `: 2;`  in front of each command to indicate which session you should use; you can safely copy and paste even these prompts):

```
: 1; mkdir -p /tmp/dir/sub
: 1; touch /tmp/dir/sub/{1..4}.txt
: 1; ls /tmp/dir/sub
```

At this point you can see in the first session that we have four (empty) files, `1.txt` to `4.txt`. Now switch to the second session:

```
: 2; cd /tmp/dir/sub
: 2; ls
```

As you'd expect, you can see the four files here too. Now we'll move the directory out from underneath session 2:

```
: 1; mv /tmp/dir/sub /tmp/dir/other
: 1; ls /tmp/dir/other
```

You can still see the files, but we've renamed the directory from `sub` to `other`. Let's check back in session 2:

```
: 2; ls
ls: cannot open directory '.': No such file or directory
```

Ouch! Let's check where we think we should be, and try to change back into our current directory:

```
: 2; pwd
/tmp/dir/sub

: 2; cd "$(pwd)"
-bash: cd: /tmp/dir/sub: No such file or directory
```

Well. This session's now lost. The best bet is to start again with the (new) correct directory:

```
: 2; cd /tmp/dir/other
: 2; ls
1.txt  2.txt  3.txt  4.txt
```

Comment: I lost that terminal session, so I can't confirm that this what happened, but it seems like a reasonable explanation. Thanks!